# python2.7 installs a fake pip3.5

Tags: 18.04, pip, python-2.7

I have tried installing pip 8.1.2 through python2.7 as follows:

```
root@ubuntu18test:~# python2.7 -m easy_install pip==8.1.2
Searching for pip==8.1.2
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9c/32/004ce0852e0a127f07f358b715015763273799bd798956fa930814b60f39/pip-8.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl#sha256=6464dd9809fb34fc8df2bf49553bb11dac4c13d2ffa7a4f8038ad86a4ccb92a1
Best match: pip 8.1.2
Processing pip-8.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing pip-8.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl to /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
writing requirements to /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-8.1.2-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO/requires.txt
Adding pip 8.1.2 to easy-install.pth file
Installing pip script to /usr/local/bin
Installing pip3.5 script to /usr/local/bin
Installing pip3 script to /usr/local/bin

Installed /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-8.1.2-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for pip==8.1.2
Finished processing dependencies for pip==8.1.2
```

However, as you can see from the output, it has created wrappers named `pip3` and `pip3.5` instead of `pip2` and `pip2.7`. Checking `pip3.5 --version` reveals that it is still using `python2.7`:

```
root@ubuntu18test:~# pip3.5 --version
pip 8.1.2 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-8.1.2-py2.7.egg (python 2.7)
```

And checking `python3 --version` reveals that it is not even Python 3.5:

```
root@ubuntu18test:~# python3 --version
Python 3.6.7
```

I need Python 2.7 and pip 8.1.2 with a working wrapper script for "legacy reasons", though pip might be upgradable with a small amount of effort.

Is there any way to get this specific version of pip for Python 2.7 with the correct wrapper script names?

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this issue. What fixed it for me was running `pip uninstall pip` and then `python2.7 -m easy_install pip==8.1.2` again.